# Roots of $x^3-x+1$

Tags: roots, factoring, radicals, cubics

I am trying to find nice explicit formulas for the roots of the polynomial $x^3-x+1$. Is there some clever way to write down the roots in a reasonably easy way? I found the roots, but my expressions involve tedious terms with multiple roots $(\ldots + (\ldots)^{1/2})^{1/3}+( \ldots -(\ldots)^{1/2})^{1/3}$ and fractions, pretty much what Mathematica drops out as well.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "reasonably easy to write down", but I don't think one can improve any on the form you mention. This is generally the case for cubics irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, and we can quickly check that $x^3 - x + 1$ is such a cubic using the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: Dear Travis, I assume that there could possibly be a way to write the roots using the exponential function or without nested roots. As it is the case with $x^3-3$, which is also irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: The only general formula is Cardano's formula, which involves nested roots, which may simplify only for special values of the coefficients.

Comment: Dear Bernard, I am not looking for a general formula, but only for a simple way to write down the roots of the given polynomial. What I wrote down is basically Cardano's formula.

Comment: And this is what you will get almost always. The Cardano form. Unless we have a very special polynomial.

Comment: Dear Henno, how do you know that this is not a special polynomial?

Comment: It depends on what one means by "special", but one can get some idea of what this ought to mean by looking at the form of Cardano's equation for a depressed cubic $x^3 + p x + q$ and spotting where the discriminant occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a ***special*** polynomial, but you still have to use Cardano's formula to express it. Let $x \to -P$, then,

$$P^3-P-1 = 0$$

Its unique real root $P \approx 1.3247$ is called the *[plastic constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number)* and plays a role similar to the *golden ratio*. Various expressions for it are,

$$\begin{aligned}
P &= \frac{(9+\sqrt{69})^{1/3}+(9-\sqrt{69})^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}\cdot9^{1/3}}\\[2.5mm]
&=\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\dots}}}\\[2.5mm]
&=\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cos\big(\tfrac{1}{3}\arccos(\tfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\big) \big) 
\end{aligned}$$

**P.S.** Incidentally, the plastic constant $P$ can be found in the vertices of the [*snub icosidodecadodecahedron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_icosidodecadodecahedron),

$\hskip2.8in$[image: Snub icosidodecadodecahedron]

$\hskip1.3in$(*Image courtesy of wikipedia and [Robert Webb's Stella software](http://www.software3d.com/Stella.php)*)